# mysql multiple rows for one user, nested loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, nested

My colleague has put together a SQL select that outputs the following array:

```
            Array
            (
                                    [0] => Array
                                            (
                                    [total_completion_time] => 163
                                    [promotion_id] => 1
                                    [challenge_id] => 1
                                    [userId] => 2
                                    [display_name] => laxadmin
                                    [completion_time] => 163
                                    [completion_time_mins] => 0
                                    [completion_time_secs] => 0
                                    [completion_time_mmss] => 0:0
                                    [score] => 40
            )

    [1] => Array
            (
                                    [total_completion_time] => 345
                                    [promotion_id] => 1
                                    [challenge_id] => 1
                                    [userId] => 1
                                    [display_name] => siteadmin
                                    [completion_time] => 345
                                    [completion_time_mins] => 5
                                    [completion_time_secs] => 45
                                    [completion_time_mmss] => 5:45
                                    [score] => 50
            )

    [2] => Array
            (
                                    [total_completion_time] => 345
                                    [promotion_id] => 1
                                    [challenge_id] => 1
                                    [userId] => 3
                                    [display_name] => mdeville
                                    [completion_time] => 345
                                    [completion_time_mins] => 0
                                    [completion_time_secs] => 0
                                    [completion_time_mmss] => 0:0
                                    [score] => 0
            )

    [3] => Array
            (
                                    [total_completion_time] => 943
                                    [promotion_id] => 1
                                    [challenge_id] => 1
                                    [userId] => 4
                                    [display_name] => Matthew DeVille
                                    [completion_time] => 163
                                    [completion_time_mins] => 2
                                    [completion_time_secs] => 43
                                    [completion_time_mmss] => 2:43
                                    [score] => 90
            )

    [4] => Array
            (
                                    [total_completion_time] => 943
                                    [promotion_id] => 1
                                    [challenge_id] => 3
                                    [userId] => 4
                                    [display_name] => Matthew DeVille
                                    [completion_time] => 90
                                    [completion_time_mins] => 1
                                    [completion_time_secs] => 30
                                    [completion_time_mmss] => 1:30
                                    [score] => 30
            )

    [5] => Array
            (
                                    [total_completion_time] => 943
                                    [promotion_id] => 1
                                    [challenge_id] => 4
                                    [userId] => 4
                                    [display_name] => Matthew DeVille
                                    [completion_time] => 90
                                    [completion_time_mins] => 1
                                    [completion_time_secs] => 30
                                    [completion_time_mmss] => 1:30
                                    [score] => 35
            )

    [6] => Array
            (
                                    [total_completion_time] => 943
                                    [promotion_id] => 1
                                    [challenge_id] => 5
                                    [userId] => 4
                                    [display_name] => Matthew DeVille
                                    [completion_time] => 300
                                    [completion_time_mins] => 5
                                    [completion_time_secs] => 0
                                    [completion_time_mmss] => 5:0
                                    [score] => 30
            )

    [7] => Array
            (
                                    [total_completion_time] => 943
                                    [promotion_id] => 1
                                    [challenge_id] => 6
                                    [userId] => 4
                                    [display_name] => Matthew DeVille
                                    [completion_time] => 300
                                    [completion_time_mins] => 5
                                    [completion_time_secs] => 0
                                    [completion_time_mmss] => 5:0
                                    [score] => 20
            )
```

)

He also provided the following code to loop through the results and create a table with the following headers:

user | 
challenge 1 time | 
challenge 2 time | 
challenge 3 time | 
challenge 4 time | 
challenge 5 time | 
challenge 6 time | 
challenge 7 time | 
total time |

```
<?php
for ($x=0; $x < $results_length; $x++) {
    $row = $results[$x]; // get next row from results
    $userId = $row["userId"]; // get userId from row

    // by default, we'll expect to continue to build UI display for current user
    $beginNewUserDisplay = false;

    if ($userId !== $currentUserId) {
        // if not first user, we need to close the current table row
        if ($currentUserId != -1) {
        // if we haven't filled in one table cell for each possible result
            // do that now...
            while ($challengesCtr <= $TOTAL_CHALLENGES_CT) {
                // this means we're missing results we need
                // to properly display the table so we add in blank cells
                echo "<td></td>";
                $challengesCtr = $challengesCtr+1;
            }

            // display total time
            // TODO: verify this is the correct display value
            echo "<td>".$row["total_completion_time"]. "-" .$row['userId']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

    // Regardless, we need to start a new table row
    // no more results for previous user, starting UI display for new user
    $currentUserId = $userId;
    $beginNewUserDisplay = true;

    // reset the results counter
    $challengesCtr = 1;

    }



    if ($beginNewUserDisplay == true) {
        // start UI for new User's results
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['userId']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['display_name']. "-" .$row['userId']."</td>";  
    } else {
        // continue UI for current User's results
        $challengeId = $row["challenge_id"];
        while ($challengesCtr < $challengeId) {
            // if this executes it means we're missing results
            // we need to properly display the table so we add in blank cells
            echo "<td></td>";
            $challengesCtr = $challengesCtr+1;
        }

        // echo table cell current challenge time here
        // TODO: verify this is the correct display value
        echo "<td>".$row['completion_time_mmss']."</td>";

        // increment our results counter
        $challengesCtr = $challengesCtr+1;
    }

}
?>
```

The problem is that the loop is skipping over most of the first user's data and the table is missing the last two columns.

You can see the results here: http://65.242.11.205/leaderboard/

I can usually figure out nested loops, but this one has me paralyzed.

Comment: what is $TOTAL_CHALLENGES_CT?

Comment: Your link does not work and what you exactly trying to display, all data on a table?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't set the first $currentUserId. And it would help alot to see the SQL I recon, since it could have something to do with joins or however the SQL is designed.